# Windows 7 user home folder set to TEMP.username.000 after power fault

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows 7 Basic and after a power fault all my files, desktop background and program links have gone. When I open Command Prompt, it shows me C:\Users\TEMP.username.000, but I can find all my original files on C:\Users\username.

How can I point my home folder to C:\Users\username again?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. Login in as Administrator.
2. Right click on Profile folder
3. Select **Properties** Option
4. Click Security Tab
5. Click Advanced button
6. Click Owner tab
7. Replace owner to the expected owner

*Note: I didn't get a chance to try this but I hope it will work.*

Other way, you can fix by following **[Microsoft - Fix a corrupted user profile - To copy files to the new user profile](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7)** steps.